# Is my school's server essentially the same thing as something like Apache or Xampp?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, server, phpmyadmin

This may be a no brainer, but I just want to be sure. First a quick background...

I go to a community college. This college has a server, `ps11.pstcc.edu`, that I can upload files to.

I was assigned a semester-long project to create a web application. I chose to create a car-pooling application where students can create an account, and then submit "car-pool posts" for other students to see. The point of the app is to connect students at my school who are in need of some form of alternative transportation.

Now, I know I'm going to need a couple of things like:

- A server to host the site (I am currently using the `ps11.pstcc.edu` server I mentioned above).
- A database to store to user account information (name, email, password, etc.)

Here's where I'm confused:

- Nearly all of the tutorials/guides I have researched about user account systems involve using a web server like Apache or Xampp. Many of these guides also use phpmyadmin to manage the MySQL database that holds the user account data.

NOTE: I am not in anyway asking for "homework help". I am mainly confused about the 'relationship' I will need between my school's server, a database, and phpmyadmin. I am simply trying to understand the steps and/or software I will need in order to implement a user account system on my web page hosted on my school's server: `ps11.pstcc.edu`.

Comment: You're explaining your situation but whats the actual question?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. Most webservers use Apache (and "Xampp" is just a distro/installer for that). Now, if that specific school server of yours is also running Apache *and* PHP *and* MySQL is a different question. There are different web site backend languages (Perl, Python, Brainfuck).

Comment: It's not something like Apache, it's Apache, as easily seen from the headers or the content of the page at /.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTTP server is a piece of software that listens for HTTP requests and responds to them. Apache is an HTTP server.

A RDBMS is a common form of database. MySQL is an example of one.

PHPMyAdmin is a piece of software, written in PHP (a programming language), that gives a web based user interface to MySQL.

It is possible for HTTP servers to be configured to execute a program (such as PHPMyAdmin) in response to a URL being requested and to use the output of that program as the response.

XAMPP is a package that bundles up Apache, MySQL and a few other things.

`ps11.pstcc.edu` is a hostname, visiting http://ps11.pstcc.edu shows that it is running an HTTP server. What other services it may be running are not obvious from the outside. You should ask your system administrator what services are available on it for you to use.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying some things.So when you log into your mysql database via the terminal, is that the same as you logging into the database through phpmyadmin? Is phpmyadmin just a GUI version of the mysql client?

Comment: They are different clients written by different people (the MySQL command line client is provided by Oracle while PHPMyAdmin is third party software), but they are both general purpose clients for MySQL.